# Grid plotting in Python with coordinates and a map image

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid

I'm fairly new to using python and I'm seeking help on a small project I'm working on.

So firstly I want to make a 10x10 grid out of coordinates and then add a loop function that can randomly pick a cell and somehow store the cell coordinates it has picked without selecting the same cell twice.

So far I have come up with this.

```
x = 1
y = 1

scale = 10

nn = []

for x in range(1,scale+1):
    mm = []
    for y in range(1,scale+1):
        xy = [x,y]
        mm.append(xy)
        #print(xy)
        y=+1
    nn.append(mm)
    x=+1

Out:[[[1, 1],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 3],
  [1, 4],
  [1, 5],
  [1, 6],
    etc
```

The next part is where I'm struggling.

```
import random
r = random.randint(1,10)
x = 1
y = r

xy = [x,y]
print(xy)
while x < 10:

    # direction North=1, East=2, South=3
    if y == 1:
        dir = [random.randint(0,1),random.randint(0,1)]
    elif y == 10:
        dir = [random.randint(0,1),random.randint(-1,0)]
    else:
        dir = [random.randint(0,1),random.randint(-1,1)]

    xy = [(a + b) for (a, b) in zip(xy, dir)]

    x = xy[0]
    y = xy[1]

if xy == [(a + b) for (a, b) in zip(xy, dir)]:
    pass
else:
    print(xy)
```

Eventually I would like to plot the coordinates onto a grid and then put a map image over the grid.

This is my first question so please excuse mistakes and code quotes.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not completely following how each code block relates to each other.  What I think you're looking for is a `set`.  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets . On each loop, check the set if the new value exists.  if not, add it, else try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, you're trying to get non repetitive random sample from a grid of coordinates, This can be done much more easily like this:

```
import random
grid = [(x,y) for x in range(10) for y in range(10)] # grid points
randomset = random.sample(grid, 5) # get 5 random element from grid
```

Result:

```
>>> randomset
[(6, 6), (4, 7), (7, 7), (1, 7), (0, 3)] # each coordinate will be unique.
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer it did indeed help! Can you help me plot the x,y onto a 10x10 grid like format. Thank you!

Comment: 2D grid for visualisation.  grid_array = np.array(grid)  -- grid=np.meshgrid(grid_array)